The value of citation entity field 'citation.appearance.abstract' exceeds the length limit. The maximum length is '480' characters
I have a problem integrating Azure OpenAI with Microsoft Teams through the Teams toolkit. The response generated by the API exceeds the character limit allowed in Teams, which causes constant errors when displaying the response in the chat. This is mainly due to the quote content field returned by Azure Search, which contains a large volume of data. Despite several attempts to format the output and adjust the index settings in Azure Search, the problem persists. As mentioned in other forums, this problem may be related to the 40 KB limit imposed by Microsoft Teams. I am asking for help in finding a solution to manage this limit without losing important information.
  azureopenai:app:error [onTurnError] unhandled error: RestError: Error while parsing citation entity with id: 2. Detailed error message: The value of citation entity field 'citation.appearance.abstract' exceeds the length limit. The maximum length is '480' characters, but the provided length is '498' characters. +0ms
  azureopenai:app:error RestError: Error while parsing citation entity with id: 2. Detailed error message: The value of citation entity field 'citation.appearance.abstract' exceeds the length limit. The maximum length is '480' characters, but the provided length is '498' characters.
  azureopenai:app:error     at handleErrorResponse (C:\Users\Nicolas Tennett\Downloads\AraucoBotv1\node_modules\@azure\core-http\src\policies\deserializationPolicy.ts:274:17)
  azureopenai:app:error     at C:\Users\Nicolas Tennett\Downloads\AraucoBotv1\node_modules\@azure\core-http\src\policies\deserializationPolicy.ts:179:47
  azureopenai:app:error     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  azureopenai:app:error     at async ThrottlingRetryPolicy.sendRequest (C:\Users\Nicolas Tennett\Downloads\AraucoBotv1\node_modules\@azure\core-http\src\policies\throttlingRetryPolicy.ts:66:22)
  azureopenai:app:error     at async ConnectorClient.sendOperationRequest (C:\Users\Nicolas Tennett\Downloads\AraucoBotv1\node_modules\@azure\core-http\src\serviceClient.ts:521:23) +1ms

Error in terminal visual code
Error in terminal visual code
Error In Teams
I tried to change the content to not retrievable in azure search of the index, however it gives another error.
change the content to not retrievable
error in OpenAI Studio

Does it work correctly in your local environment and when you deploy it to Teams, the responses fail due to the character limit in the Teams channel (480 characters)?

Correct, when running it in the local environment it works correctly without the problem of the characters, however when I test in Teams, the same question I asked the bot, it generates it as seen in the terminal but can not send it to teams because the quote that comes in the api exceeds 480 characters.

Thanks! There is an ongoing discussion with engineering team regarding this issue. Once we hear any update, we will respond in this thread.

@Prasad-MSFT , could you tell me where specifically they are checking this error? I entered the link you shared, however I don't see anything related to the maximum characters error.

@Prasad-MSFT any workarounds to prevent this from happening? A system prompt asking not to display citations does not work.

We are able to repro this issue locally as well and have raised a bug for the same. We will inform you once we get any further update from engineering team. Thanks!

According to latest update from engineering team, this is as designed. The citation popup has very limited space and is intended to display a snippet of the underlying reference and not display a huge document. Users can click on the title that contains reference link (if sent in the message payload) to see the full reference of the citation. Currently engineering team is working on adding support to add larger citation content that can be sent in the form of an adaptive card. This feature is currently being rolled out. We will update you in this thread once it is rolled out publicly.
